Smoothing a scalar field in SPH derivation
I'm learning about the smoothed particle hydrodynamics (SPH) method.
In the original paper, Gingold and Monaghan arrive at the following expression for the discretized smoothed version of a scalar field $A$:
$$\frac{M}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N W(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_j)\frac{A(\mathbf{r}_j)}{\rho(\mathbf{r}_j)},$$
where $\rho$ is the density and $M=\int \rho(\mathbf{r})d\mathbf{r}$.
My understanding is that this is derived in the following way.
We first define a smoothed version $A_S$ of $A$ as
$$A_S(\mathbf{r}) = (A * W)(\mathbf{r}) = \int A(\mathbf{r'})W(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}') d\mathbf{r}'.$$
Then, since the sample points $\mathbf{r}_i$ come from a distribution with PDF given by $p(\mathbf{r}) = \rho(\mathbf{r})/M$, we can approximate the integral in the expression for $A_S$ using Monte Carlo with importance sampling:
$$A_S(\mathbf{r})
\approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N A(\mathbf{r}_i) W (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_i)\frac{1}{p(\mathbf{r}_i)}
= \frac{M}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N  W(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_i)\frac{A(\mathbf{r}_i)}{\rho(\mathbf{r}_i)}.$$
What I cannot understand is how other texts arrive at a generalization (?) of the above:
$$A_S(\mathbf{r}) \approx \sum_{i=1}^N m_i W(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_i)\frac{A(\mathbf{r}_i)}{\rho(\mathbf{r}_i)}$$
(notice that here the particles can have different masses $m_i$).
Is my understanding of the derivation I outlined here correct? If so, how can one obtain the last formula above?
